# Azure Active Directory exception thrown while fetching access token

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get graph api access token in my c# application using GetAccessTokenForUserAsync().

It throws below error :

Error = invalid_grant
Error_description = "AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/***********-*****-************/'
does not exist in tenant 'ABC' and cannot access the application '*****-****-*****-****'(xyz-app) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account

Comment: Does the user exist in the directory that you use? What method of authentication are you using?

Comment: User Exist in his own tenant. I am using (tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync)

Comment: var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(_azureAd.ClientId)
                        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                        .WithClientSecret(_azureAd.ClientSecret)
                        .Build();

            try
            {
                _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(
     scopes).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

Comment: Is the app registered as a multi-tenant application? I.e. does it allow sign ins from other directories or only the directory where the app was created in?

Comment: the error message is clear, the user which signed in the the app doesn't exist in the tenant which azure ad application registered. You must have an azure ad app in the  tenant, pls use the user account which in the same tenant to sign in.

Comment: any update on it?

Comment: It resolved, Some issues were at our azure tenant AD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the user and Application exists in the different tenants. Make sure to check the user exists in the Azure AD Application tenant. Try to sign-in and sign-out.

Check whether the **sign-in URL** you are making use is valid:

- Multitenant applications
  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations`
- Multitenant and personal accounts
   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`
- Personal accounts only
  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers`

Please check whether the **guest user has been invited to the tenant** like below:

[image]

- Try clearing the ***browser cookies/log-in via Incognito***.
- You can also make use of **`domain_hint`** parameter which specifies from which domain Azure AD User should be from. You can configure from both client and server side.

**If the issue still persists, please refer the below MsDoc:**

[Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant - Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist)

Comment: I am able to login through my tenant. I have angular app and backend .Net core app. 
I first gave admin consent to my new tenant using login.microsoft.com/my tenantId / client Id of my backend app.

Onboarding is successful. After logging in , i tried to fetch my users from graph API using tokenAquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(my tenant Id). It fails by giving exception I written on top.